# Override file from package in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I would like to use my core project and import it into my second project. I point to the App.js and so the entire core project is now visible in my second project.

However, now I would like to override the logo that is being displayed at the top.

Is there a way to override files from a dependency that I use? I use the `file-loader` and I am pretty sure that I can use this in some way, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Imported packages behaves as normal objects and methods. So if your component exposes the variables then can be accessed before instantiate it.

This is not a good practice at all, but is doable.

**IE:** You can change the PropTypes of a component:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Menu, Dropdown, Icon, Statistic } from 'semantic-ui-react';
Dropdown.propTypes.text = PropTypes.any;
```